# scrollTop position inconsistent when window reloaded pre-scrolled down

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure this one out for a few days so here I am, asking for help.

**The Goal:** The goal is to simply add a class to a div once the scroll window position meets the div position. Works fine until the 'problem'

**Problem:** Positions seem to be improperly calculated when the page is reloaded anywhere but the VERY top. When loaded with the page slightly scrolled, the calculations don't seem to be close.

```
$(window).load(function(){
     var subnavPos = document.getElementById("secondaryNav").getBoundingClientRect().top;
     var topnavPos = document.getElementById("fullDnav").getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
     console.log(subnavPos);
     $(window).scroll(function() {

       var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + 66;

       console.log(scroll);
       console.log(subnavPos);

       if (scroll >= subnavPos) {
         secondaryNav.classList.add("sticky");
       } else {
         secondaryNav.classList.remove("sticky");
       }

     })
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrote script below and now functioning properly

```
var stickMe = $('#secondaryNav').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      var currentPos = $(window).scrollTop() + 66;
      if (currentPos >= stickMe) {
        $('#secondaryNav').addClass("sticky");
      } else {
        $('#secondaryNav').removeClass("sticky");
      }
    });
```